# Can I return a reference?

Tags: c++

If i need to return a referenced value, this function code works?

```
&int returnvalue(){
    return &property;
}
```

I want to return just a reference to a property of my class, it's possible to do?

Comment: http://www.functionx.com/cpp/examples/returnreference.htm , http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/74a-returning-values-by-value-reference-and-address/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can return references in C++. However, you need to get the syntax right:

```
int &returnvalue() {
    return property;
}
```

In the function type declaration, `int` comes before the `&`. In the `return` statement, you don't want to take the *address* of `property`, because that is a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible:

```
#include <iostream>
int i = 2;

int& a()
{
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    int& j = a();
    std::cout << j;
}
```

outputs: `2`

Answer (score 1):

you can also pass a variable by reference, then change it in the function. This will change the original variable.

```
int main()
{
  int a = 1;

  cout << "a before it is passed by reference: " << a << endl;

  increment(a);

  cout << "a after it has been passed by reference: " << a << endl;

  return 0;
}

void increment(int &number)
{
  number++;
}
```

output would be:

> a before it is passed by reference: 1
>
> a after it has been passed by reference: 2

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass{
 private:
   Member _member;
 public:
   Member& getMember(){
     return _member;
   }
};
```

but this is an encapsulation violation so don't do this :).

Answer (score -2):

```
int* returnvalue() {
    int* property; 
    // setting protperty     
    return property;
}
```

Comment: And you are returning a temporary variable.